# Parameterize build with GIT_COMMIT from other job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Essentially I need to parameterise a job with the git_commit id from another job since i use this for some artefact naming.

I know that if i set the parameter name to "job" and then in the pipeline try to echo $job or $job_NAME then I get the object or the Name of the job.

Comment: So what's the issue? Could you share some code please?

Comment: There is no code to share in this case. Issue is described in the first sentence. I need to parameterise another pipeline with a variable from one other pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

First pipeline "MainProject" :

```
stage('test') {
    build job: 'SubProject', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'param1', value: 'test_param']]
    }
```

Second pipeline "SubProject", setup with 1 string parameter "param1" :

```
stage('DoIt') {
    echo "$param1"  
}
```

Will echo your value.